# Automatic tracking of build number in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, versioning

In Visual Studio 2005, is there an easy way to automatically increment the assembly/file build numbers after a successful build?

Emphasis on ***easy***. I would like to track my build version, without having to set up CruiseControl or some similar tool.

Comment: can you add some details on how you wish to increment your build number?  There are different solutions for different needs.

Comment: Just BuildNumber++ would be fine - starting by 0 end ending with an overflow ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this project and include it your .proj file

This url might be of use [Updating Porj build number](https://web.archive.org/web/20100515233947/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/narent/archive/2006/02/15/69532.aspx)

This didn't fit my needs and I took to adding this as a build.proj which works a treat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Project DefaultTargets="Build"  
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/> <PropertyGroup>
    <Major>1</Major>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
    <Build>0</Build>
    <Revision>0</Revision>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDir>C:\svn\Infrastructure</BuildDir> </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SolutionsToBuild Include="Infrastructure.sln"/>   </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="ChangeDataAccessAssemblyInfo">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildDir)\Builds" Condition="Exists('$(BuildDir)\Builds')" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionsToBuild)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" Targets="Rebuild" />   </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="Build\Logging\Logging.UnitTests.dll" />   </ItemGroup>



  <Target Name="ChangeDataAccessAssemblyInfo" >
    <Message Text="Writing ChangeDataAccessAssemblyInfo file for 1"/>
    <Message Text="Will update $(BuildDir)\DataAccess\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="VB"
       OutputFile="$(BuildDir)\DataAccess\My Project\AssemblyInfo_new.vb"          

       AssemblyTitle="Data Access Layer"
       AssemblyDescription="Message1"
       AssemblyCompany="http://somewebiste"
       AssemblyProduct="the project"
       AssemblyCopyright="Copyright notice"
       ComVisible="true"
       CLSCompliant="true"
       Guid="hjhjhkoi-9898989"
       AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).1.1"
       AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).5.7"
       Condition="$(Revision) != '0' "
       ContinueOnError="false" />

    <Message Text="Updated Assembly File Info" 
             ContinueOnError="false"/>   </Target>   </Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Publish options might be what you want... (def. available for C#, not sure abuut C++).

In studio, right click on the project file, and go to Properties, then select the "Publish" tab. There is an option there for auto-incrementing revision number.

Comment: Does not work for me :-(
My project is a module that is compiled to a class library, and you can not publish those. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah - sorry that can't help then.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a little macro, which increments the version?

Or what about this VS [AddIn](http://yogesh.jagotagroup.com/blog/page/Solution-level-Auto-build-increment-Add-In.aspx) ?

Comment: What kind of macro, and how is it triggered?